# Handlebars variable in HAML not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, haml

I have a `.haml` file having `handlebar` template in it. In template I am passing `handlebar variable` to a `rails helper function` . But in rails helper function it is unable to parse the value of the variable and takes it as string. My handlebar line looks like

```
%span{:class => apply_label_class('{{change}}')}
```

Where `{{change}}` is the handlebar variable . When I go to `apply_lable_class` funtion which looks like

```
def apply_label_class(change)

  return '' unless change

end
```

The change should be some integer value but it is always `'{{change}}'`. .

So any guide how can I pass variable of handlebars to rails helper in .haml file?

Comment: Client-side handlebars? Where does the client side get the value of "change" from?

Answer (score 2):

Handlebars templates are evaluated in the browser, long after they have been processed by Haml on the server.

If you want to have logic that depends on the value of a Handlebars variable, it has to be implemented in the clientside Javascript, probably as a Handlebars helper.

EDIT: your second example works because the string `"{{change}}"` by itself satisfies the condition and the final template has the result of the evaluation, which is `{{change}}` - try setting the variable to 0 to see that the condition doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But when I use `=link_to '{{mycustomurl}}', custom_url?('{{custom_id}}')`, it works well and parse variable value. Why then?

Comment: Because the template strings are used as strings here, and not evaluated by Haml. There is no logic connected to their (future) value.